# VBA-Count and collect every found match in regular expression

Tags: regex, vba

A am trying to count and collect all found matches of regex in vba.You can see my progress here but the problem is that the count doesn`t work. When the matches are collected I have to check If the value is not in the following list:

PAGE_BREAK;NEW_LINE;EMPTY_LINE;FS:;/FS:;b;/b;COLOR:;integer>;/COLOR:;IMAGE:

is available in BY Variables sheet .The matches are only the values with brackets except the above examples.Here are some screenshots:

```
Sub simpleRegex()
Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = "\<.*?\>"
Dim strReplace As String: strReplace = ""
Dim regEx As New RegExp
Dim strInput As String
Dim Myrange As Range
Dim match As Object
Dim newArray() As Integer
Set Myrange = Sheets("BY Blocks").Range("D10:D12")

    For Each cell In Myrange
    If strPattern <> "" Then
        strInput = cell.Value

        With regEx
            .Global = True
            .MultiLine = True
            .IgnoreCase = False
            .Pattern = strPattern
        End With

        If regEx.Test(strInput) Then
            MsgBox ("A cell match with the pattern:   ") & strPattern
        Else
            MsgBox ("No cell match with the pattern:   ") & strPattern
        End If
        Set objMatches = regEx.Execute(strInput)
     For Each match In objMatches             '

     a = match.SubMatches.Count
     For i = 0 To a - 1
    MsgBox match.SubMatches.Item(i)  'display each group
Next
Next
Set objReg = Nothing

    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Please could you include sample data perhaps using a [markdown table generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) so we can copy and use for testing. Also, please show the expected outcome.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am not entirely clear on what you are doing, as noted in other answer you are not retrieving submatches as no groups applied in regex, but here is the count of matches, ignoring the items you listed. I also print out to the immediate window each match accepted and rejected.

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub simpleRegex()

    Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = "\<.*?\>"
    Dim strReplace As String: strReplace = ""
    Dim regEx As New RegExp
    Dim strInput As String
    Dim Myrange As Range
    Dim currMatch As match
    Set Myrange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BY Blocks").Range("D1:D7")
    Dim ignoreItems()
    ignoreItems = Array("<PAGE_BREAK>", "<NEW_LINE>", "<EMPTY_LINE>", "<FS:>", "</FS:>", "<b>", "</b>", "<COLOR:>", "<integer>", _
                        "</COLOR:>", "<IMAGE:>")
    Dim currCell As Range

    For Each currCell In Myrange
        If strPattern <> vbNullString Then
            strInput = currCell.Value

            With regEx
                .Global = True
                .MultiLine = True
                .IgnoreCase = False
                .Pattern = strPattern
            End With
            '
            '            If regEx.Test(strInput) Then
            '                MsgBox ("A cell match with the pattern:   ") & strPattern
            '            Else
            '                MsgBox ("No cell match with the pattern:   ") & strPattern
            '            End If
            Dim objMatches As MatchCollection, counter As Long
            Set objMatches = regEx.Execute(strInput)
            Dim matchRange As Range
            Set matchRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BY Variables").Range("A1:A4") '<== Change as appropriate

            For Each currMatch In objMatches
                If IsError(Application.match(currMatch, ignoreItems, 0)) Then
                    Debug.Print "Accept: " & currMatch
                    counter = counter + 1

                    If Not IsError(Application.match(currMatch, matchRange, 0)) Then MsgBox currMatch

                Else
                    Debug.Print "Reject: " & currMatch
                End If

            Next currMatch
            Set regEx = Nothing

        End If
    Next currCell
    MsgBox "# matches accepted = " & counter
End Sub
```

**Immediate window:**

[image: Immediate window]

**Msgbox:**

[image: Msgbox]

**Input data:**

[image: Data]

Comment: Thank you! It worked perfectly :) Now the only thing left is to compare each match if it is available in by variable sheet in column A -http://prntscr.com/jni85e

Comment: Use Application.Match and test if error when seeking match value in column A.

Answer (score 1):

The regex you are using does not give submatches - only matches. If you want submatches, you need to put some parentheses in your expression. If not - just iterate over the Matches collection

Comment: Before that expression I used <([a-z] | [A-Z] | [0-9] | \. | - | _)+> but its syntax is wrong and no matches are found. With the above expression everything is ok

Comment: @user3701825 - then you'll have to change your code accordingly. Remove the `for i` part and change the MsgBox to `Msgbox match`