# VBA get a value in brackets from a cell and check if it is available in other sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to get a specific cell value in brackets and check if this value is in other sheet. This is the column with the possible values:

StrS Format

HEADER

NOBREAK

IGNORE

REPEATABLE …-n can be up to 100

I want to split the string in the cell, check if its value is one of the above, if it  is equal with "REPEATABLE" extract the following block specifications: .  If  is not defined in “BY Variables” show error. This is a similar issue with this one:
[VBA-Count and collect every found match in regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50561496/vba-count-and-collect-every-found-match-in-regular-expression) -again have to get values with brackets

Here is my code:

```
Public Function IsItGood(aWord As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim s As String

    s = "|"                                      '-means or
    'tmp = s & aWord & s
    tmp = Replace(s & aWord & s, ",", "")
    patern = ""
    patern = patern & "HEADER|NOBREAK|REPEATABLE" & s

    If InStr(1, patern, tmp) > 0 Then
        IsItGood = True
    Else
        IsItGood = False
    End If
End Function

Function check_cell_values()

    On Error Resume Next

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim msg As String
    msg = ""

    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim a As Variant

    arr = Split(Target, " ")

    For Each a In arr
        If Target.Column = 10 And (Target.Row > 2 And Target.Row <= 308) Then

            If IsItGood(a) Then
                msg = msg & vbCrLf & (" In cell" + Target.Address(0, 0)) & vbCrLf & a & vbCrLf + "is ok"
            Else
                msg = msg & vbCrLf & (" In cell" + Target.Address(0, 0)) & vbCrLf & a & vbCrLf + "is invalid value"
                Application.Undo
            End If
        End If
    Next a

    If msg <> "" Then MsgBox msg
    check_cell_values = msg

End Function

Sub by_blocks_check()

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim func1

    func1 = check_cell_values()

End Sub
```

I think instead of a regular expression it is better to use an array from the possible values but I don`t know how to get the  value after "Repeatable".

Example output:

[image: Output]

Comment: Ah..do .you mean upto 100 words within <> in a cell? And those words come from the list you have specified?

Comment: But these 100 words within <>  can be only with REPEATABLE

Comment: http://prntscr.com/jwl99u So this is an example output- I think with this image is better because the data is too much to be used with the table generator

Comment: A word of caution... you are switching off EnableEvents and not switching it back on. You are also leaving an unclosed On Error Resume Next which is masking any  errors you should be handling.  On Error Resume Next should be just before where you expect an error and be closed as soon as possible after with On Error GoTo O.

Comment: Sorry to focus on other elements at present: Target should be declared as range and unless it is used within an Event I would use a different name for that variable. You then access it's .Value property to obtain your string which you split to populate arr. You also need to state where Target is coming from. It feels like it (your function check_cell_values) should be a Worksheet Event but it is not declared at such;  or a function that receives Target as an argument from such an event.

Comment: You can store strings to check for in an array then do If Not IsError(Application.Match(searchTerm, array,0) ) Then .... 'value found in array

Comment: [Edit] the link into the question and explain why it is relevant.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173378/discussion-between-hris-and-qharr).